# LenB Function is Not Working (VBA)

Tags: vba

I am currently working on an **Access 2010** application which have textboxes that accepts inputs in Japanese characters (KANJI). As soon as the focus (On Exit event) is lost in the textbox, it checks if all the characters are in double-bytes otherwise it will generate a warning message. You may refer to the code below:

```
If LenB(StrConv(Trim(strJapanese), vbFromUnicode)) <> Len(Trim(strJapanese)) * 2 Then
    'Inform the user to input double-byte Japanese characters
End If
```

The problem is that even if I input double-byte characters in the textbox, the condition above is satisfied. This means that the byte-length of the string is equal to its length.

Please note that using this Access tool in my colleague's computer and inputting Japanese characters will not satisfy the condition above - which is the expected behavior. Is this a problem with my environment? We are using the same operating system and same MS Office version so I don't understand why we're not having the same results.

I would appreciate any help regarding this matter. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide example input so that we can replicate?

Comment: Hi Macro Man, thank you reaching out. You may try to set StrJapanese = 兵庫県

The idea is that the **LenB** of this string should result to 6 while its Len is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about LenB, but if you just want to check whether a string contains kanji, that's much easier to do simply by looping through each character in the string, and checking AscW(char). That will return a number representing the Unicode value of the character, and all kanji are contained between &H4E00 (一) and &H9FAF (龯). The only exception to this is the kanji iteration marker 々, which is Unicode &H3005.

Note: AscW returns positive numbers from 1 to 32767 for &H1 to &H7FFF, and it returns negative numbers from -32768 to -1 for &H8000 to &HFFFF. This split happens right in the middle of the kanji Unicode block, so you can't simply use a switch statement "Case &H4E00 to &H9FAF"...you have to split it apart as "Case &H4E00 To &H7FFF, &H8000 To &H9FAF".

```
Function containsOnlyKanji(str As String) As Boolean
 If Len(str) = 0 Then Exit Function 'empty strings don't have any kanji so return false
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 1 To Len(str)
  Select Case AscW(Mid(str, i, 1))
  Case &H4E00 To &H7FFF, &H8000 To &H9FAF, &H3005: 'do nothing, these are kanji
  Case Else: Exit Function                         'non kanji! don't have to check the rest
  End Select
 Next i
 containsOnlyKanji = True 'if we've made it this far, the user must have entered only kanji
End Function
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, and I hate when people post answers that don't directly answer the question, but hopefully this will do what you need it to. (Also, if you want to include katakana and hiragana, those are contained in Unicode blocks &H30A1 to &H30FE and &H3040 to &H309F, respectively.)

Comment: Thank you Travis for your answer. I have not tried it yet but I am assuming that it will so I will mark this as an accepted answer. However my primary concern in asking this question is that my VBA code above works on my colleague's VM but not on mine. So I want to know if the problem is on the environment of my VM or if I need to download a language pack or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the below setting in Excel and set Japanese Language as Preferred,

File -> Option -> Language -> Office authoring languages and proofing